# Set a form field from a dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am attempting to populate a form field from a dialog. What i want is to click a button and some text is populated in the form field.I have this demonstration:

http://jsfiddle.net/48bU2/

Edit:I solved it.

Comment: The example doesn't make an sense? The `select image` button doesn't work? You want to set a field in your parent form _from_ the dialog?

Comment: Update: Now your link doesnt work anymore.

Comment: @Truth  silly joke never mind! :P

Comment: @username002 it does not. It redirects to an "admin review" general page, stating that your website is under review and will be down for about 2-4 hours.

Comment: @Truth,i am surprised,the link works from my computer.@gideon I thought in the lines of an input dialog,but preferred to make a selection instead on an input.

Comment: Try clearing your cache, in any way, try making a http://jsfiddle.net example please.

Comment: If your case is solved either delete the question or if you think others can learn from this, post the solution as new answer and Accept it.

Comment: For the record, browsing to http://sandsack.comoj.com/dialogs.html redirects me to http://www.000webhost.com/admin-review which says **You are seeing this page because the system administrator of 000webhost.com is currently checking this website for malicious content. This redirect page will be removed once we finish manually checking all files on this account. Since we check over 100 websites per day, it can take about 2-4 hours to complete. If you are the owner of this website, you will get an email confirmation once it's done. If you are a visitor, please come back later.** - link is dead.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I can only answer after 8 hours.I shall post my answer then.

Comment: Cheers, just don't forget us! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole html.The css and js includes are all from the jquery UI library.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Basic modal</title>
    <!--blueprint files being -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/print.css" media="print" />
    <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie.css" media="screen,projection" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- blueprint files end-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/demos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.ui.base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.ui.theme.css">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/demos.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 440,
            modal: true
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">
<form>
Image Path: <input id="example3b" name="firstname" /><br />
</form> 
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog">
    <p>Adding the modal overlay screen makes the dialog look more prominent because it dims out the page content.</p>
   <p>
An image:
<img src="images/wolf-moon.jpg" alt="Wolf Moon" width="450" height="281" />
</p>
<br />
<form name="myform" >
    Type something in here:
    <input id="example3b" />
    <input name="SetValue" type="button" value="Set Value"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">document.forms.myform.elements.SetValue.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var example3b = document.getElementById("example3b");
    // example3b === null

    var example3a = "hello";

    example3b.value = example3a;

});</script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```